# Return Postgres json_build_object as variable field from table

Tags: json, postgresql

postgesql returns the json_build_object as a parent for each grouped json array like this:

```
 {
  "stories": [{
        "json_build_object": {
          "CNN": []
        }
      },
      {
        "json_build_object": {
          "FOX": []
        }
      },
      {
        "json_build_object": {
          "Huffpost": []
        }
      },...
```

Postgresql returns the "json_build_object" as a key.
Is it possible to replace with the stories.source value returned by the group by?  Tried an ALIAS but that returned an error.

```
SELECT json_build_object(source, json_agg(stories.*))
FROM stories
GROUP BY stories.source
ORDER BY source;
```

Optimal solution would be a response like this:

```
 stories:
  CNN: [],
  FOX: []...
```

I'm sure I'm missing a best practice for returning JSON in Postgresql...

Comment: `SELECT json_object_agg(source, strs) FROM (SELECT source, array_agg(stories.*) as strs FROM stories GROUP BY stories.source ORDER BY source) as t;`?

Comment: Definitely better than my query. Thanks

Comment: Thanks @Abelisto ! would upvote if you post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `json_agg` before `json_object_agg` like this.

```
select test json_agg(json_oject_agg(...)) test;
```